# TeXstudio cannot find LaTex

Tags: texstudio, mactex

Upon opening TeXstudio for Mac I get en error. It seems that the system cannot find my TeX of LaTeX distribution.

[image]

Do notice i have MacTex installed and have it working with LyX.

I am a newbie and I have no clue how I resolve this issue.
I hope some blessed soul can help me out!

Comment: On which path is MacTeX installed? TeXstudio does only search the standard location. If it's on some other path, you'll have to specify the paths to the required latex tools at `Options -> Commands`. Then you can ignore the message (click don't warn again).

Answer (score 2):

I will had precision to Tim Hoffmann comment, as it was not enough for me:

- You can see where does TeXstudio go to get your LateX distribution with Preferences -> Commands".
- You should have at least one file in the "LateX" field and one in the "PdLateX" field. To find these I went to /Library/TeX/texbin/ and found one alias for each. Selecting these aliases one by one will fix your issue.